# How to return all errors of a schema using RestAssured

Tags: java, api, jsonschema, rest-assured, json-schema-validator

I am trying to validate a schema using RestAssured.

I have a response

```
{
"a" : 1,
"b" : 1,
"c" : 1
}
```

and I have a schema like shown below

```
{
"type" : "object",
"properties" : {
    "a" : {
        "type" : "string"
    },
    "b" : {
        "type" : "string"
    }
},
"required" : ["a", "b"],
"additionalProperties" : false
}
```

And I test it using RestAssured like shown below

```
public static void test01() {
    
    given().log().all()
    .when().get("http://localhost:8080/aaa")
    .then().assertThat().statusCode(200)
    .and().body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("static/test.json"));
}
```

When I ran the test, the error is only about the unwanted key `c`. But based on my test, it should also fail for keys `a` and `b` as the response is of an `integer` type and my schema is checking for `string`.

My question is, is there a way to return all the errors?

Error is shown below

FAILED: test01
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.

Response body doesn't match expectation.

Expected: The content to match the given JSON schema.

error: object instance has properties which are not allowed by the schema: ["c"]
level: "error"
schema: {"loadingURI":"file:/C:/Users/allen/eclipse-workspace/tsrv/target/test-classes/static/test.json#","pointer":""}
instance: {"pointer":""}
domain: "validation"
keyword: "additionalProperties"
unwanted: ["c"]

Actual: {
"a" : 1,
"b" : 1,
"c" : 1
}

Comment: The backend should return all the errors. Is the backend API returning all  errors ?

Comment: Hi Deepak, backend API meaning the json-schema-validator library that is being used by RestAssured? I dont know how to check that. But this is the library. https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator